# is google maps api key free?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, api-key

I am having this issue my app is on development and the map were working just fine . as soon as I restrict the api key the map stop working . if I change it back to unrestricted start working again . 
I been reading all day trying to figure out if I am missing something . do I need to pay for this to work ? any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps APIs are free for a wide variety of use cases, with predictable overage pricing and usage limits for APIs and annual contracts for enterprise deployments.

Your issue is probably related to how you are enabling restrictions inside Google Developers Console. Assuming you are doing this for Android, it requires you to add package name (that you can get from AndroidManifest.xml file) and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint that you can generate using following command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

Once you add these two to the console, it should be in-effect within 5 minutes of the update.

Comment: thank you for reply. yes I did all those steps . I got my own keystore and everything . but is not working the map still blank .

Answer (score 2):

[HOW TO REGISTER A FREE GOOGLE MAPS API KEY](https://www.mapsmarker.com/docs/basic-usage/how-google-maps/)

> if you want to use Google Maps as basemaps, you need to register a free API key that can be obtained from the Google API Console and enable the “Google Maps Javascript API” within Maps Marker Pro respectively Leaflet Maps Marker

Comment: In order to get this to work , first check your app package name if is the same with the api key using on the manifest, most important your app have to complete all signing application package . https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/signing/

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work , first check your app package name if is the same with the api key using on the manifest, most important your app have to complete all signing application package . https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/signing/